# Looping program behaves unpredictable

Tags: c++, loops

In the land of Puzzlevania, Aaron, Bob, and Charlie had an argument
over which one of them was the greatest puzzler of all time. To end the
argument once and for all, they agreed on a duel to the death. Aaron is a
poor shooter and only hits his target with a probability of 1/3. Bob is a
bit better and hits his target with a probability of 1/2. Charlie is an expert
marksman and never misses. A hit means a kill and the person hit drops
out of the duel.
To compensate for the inequities in their marksmanship skills, it is decided
that the contestants would fire in turns starting with Aaron, followed by Bob,
and then by Charlie. The cycle would repeat until there was one man standing.
And that man would be remembered as the greatest puzzler of all time.
 An obvious strategy is for each man to shoot at the most accurate
shooter still alive on the grounds that this shooter is the deadliest and
has the best chance of hitting back. Write a function named
startDuel that uses the shoot function to simulate an entire duel
using this strategy. It should loop until only one contestant is left,
invoking the shoot function with the proper target and probability of
hitting the target according to who is shooting. The function should
return a variable that indicates who won the duel.

My program works correctly if I let it loop hundreds or thousands times but starts to behave strangely like giving wrong outputs and running non-stop if I loop over ten thousand times.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<time.h>


void shoot(bool targetAlive[], double accuracy[],bool round[], int i, int k);
int startDuel(bool notDead[], bool round[],double accuracy[]);
void finding_maximum(bool notDead[],int& Max);
void finding_minimum(bool notDead[],bool haveShot[], int& Min);

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    int survivor,times(100),times0(0),times1(0),times2(0);
    while (times>0)
    {   
        double acc[3]={1/3.0,1/2.0,1.0}; //accuracy[0] is Aaron, accuracy[1] is Bob, accuracy[2] is Charlie
        bool Alive[3]={true,true,true}; //Alive[0] is Aaron, Alive[1] is Bob, Alive[2] is Charlie
        bool turn[3]={false,false,false}; //turn[0] is Aaron, turn[1] is Bob, turn[2] is Charlie
        survivor=startDuel(Alive,turn,acc);
        if (survivor==0)
        {
            times0++;
        }
        else if (survivor==1)
        {
            times1++;
        }
        else
        {
            times2++;
        }
        cout<<"Dueler number "<<survivor<<" survived the duel\n";
        times--;
    }
    cout<<times0<<" "<<times1<<" "<<times2<<endl;
    return 0;
}

void shoot(bool targetAlive[],double accuracy[],bool round[],int i, int k)
{//i is the one who is shot(highest accuracy), k is the shooter
    using namespace std;
    if (targetAlive[i]==true)
    {   
        srand(time(0));
        double shot;
        shot=(rand()%99+1)/100.0;
        cout<<"the shot is "<<shot<<endl;
        if (shot<accuracy[k])
        {
            cout<<"Dueler number "<<i<<" died"<<endl;
            targetAlive[i]=false;
            round[i]=true;
        }
        else
        {
            cout<<"Dueler number "<<i<<" lived"<<endl;
        }
    }
}

void finding_maximum(bool notDead[],int& Max)
{
    using namespace std;
    for (Max=2;Max>=0;Max--)
    {
        if (notDead[Max]==true)
        {
            break;
        }       
    }
}

void finding_minimum(bool notDead[],bool haveShot[],int& Min)
{
    using namespace std;
    for (Min=0;Min<=2;Min++)
    {
        if (notDead[Min]==true)
        {
            if (haveShot[Min]==false)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
int startDuel(bool notDead[], bool round[], double accuracy[])
{
    using namespace std;
    int maximum,minimum;
    do
    {
        finding_maximum(notDead,maximum);
        finding_minimum(notDead,round,minimum);
        while (maximum==minimum)
        {
            for (int n=maximum-1;n>=0;n--)
            {
                if (notDead[n]==true)
                {
                    maximum=n;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        cout<<"the shooter is dueler number "<<minimum<<endl;
        cout<<"the target is dueler number "<<maximum<<endl;
        shoot(notDead,accuracy,round,maximum,minimum);
        round[minimum]=true;
        if ((round[0]==true)&&(round[1]==true)&&(round[2]==true))
        {
            round[0]=false;
            round[1]=false;
            round[2]=false;
        }
    } while (((notDead[0]==true)&&(notDead[1]==true)&&(notDead[2]==false))||
             ((notDead[0]==false)&&(notDead[1]==true)&&(notDead[2]==true))||
             ((notDead[0]==true)&&(notDead[1]==false)&&(notDead[2]==true))||
             ((notDead[0]==true)&&(notDead[1]==true)&&(notDead[2]==true)));
    return minimum;
}
```

Comment: It looks like `finding_maximum(bool notDead[],int& Max)` can set Max to -1. And `void finding_minimum(bool notDead[],bool haveShot[],int& Min)` can set Min to 3. I mean is it possible for notDead to contain false,false,false?

Comment: Try to make a **minimal** example that reproduces your error. Often, in doing so you will find & solve the problem by yourself (which is infinitely more satisfying than being shown the solution).

Comment: Also you probably should not have `srand(time(0));` in `shoot()`

Comment: btw, don't use `rand()`, but C++'s functionality from header `<random>`

Comment: qeq, I've made my own version http://pastebin.com/LLq7zFc4. Thanks for the question, by the way

Comment: you forgot about statistics, though. > In your main function, invoke the startDuel function 1,000 timesin a loop, keeping track of how many times each contestant wins. Output the probability that each contestant will win when everyone uses the strategy of shooting at the most accurate shooter left alive.

Answer (score 2):

1. I don't think your program works correctly even with a low number of loops. It calls `srand(time(0))` every time its about to use `rand`. This resets the RNG seed to the same value (almost) every time and so `rand` produces the same sequence each time. Large `times` values only produce wonky output when it causes the execution time to be longer than one second (since you've caused `rand` to be tied to the current second), giving more opportunity for the bug (below) to kick in. Every so often, when you execute this with a low `times` value, it will still go off the rails. **Move `srand` to `main` to get correct results.**
2. The error you're asking about has to do with `finding_minimum`. There are situations where it always causes `Min == 3`. One such situation is if Charlie dies before he gets his turn and the remaining shots are misses. With `Min == 3`, `startDuel` loops infinitely.